# Duplicate file take different times to read

Tags: c#, performance, file

can anyone tell me why two files - duplicates of each other - take different times to load in memory?

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(filename,
                  FileMode.Open,
                  FileAccess.Read,
                  FileShare.Read,
                  16 * 1024,
                  FileOptions.SequentialScan);
```

It's this line that is slow (one file takes 3 times as long...)

```
fileStream.CopyTo(Form1.GlobalMS);
```

ODDLY, when I copy the file (in cmd window) and then try to load that file - it loads very fast... almost as if newly created files are somehow more accessible - could this be something to do with old files getting fragmented in someway? These are all 1G plus files by the way

Comment: change the orange text "0% ..." to at least grey text and pref green one.

Comment: At least he's consistent - no worrying about whether you might get an accept or not - you know where you stand with @ManInMoon.

Comment: What are the file sizes? How long do they take? Are they on the same disk? Are they both contiguous on disk? Is one of them cached? What buffer sizes have you tried?

Comment: Ah I just noticed these comments - what is different use of comments and replies. This seems singular to this forum.

Comment: @ManInMoon: This is not a forum. Click on "FAQ" at the top of any page, and _read_.

Comment: The polite way to bring visibility to a question on stackoverflow is to [post a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).

Comment: Jon, I have asked moderators to remove the first one

Comment: sarnold, if I had any I would!  Problem is I am trying to get answrs for my code - and I didn't realise I had to learn the intricate ways of this forum... studying hard!

Comment: I don't understand the question. The two statements do different things. The first statement opens the file, and the second one reads it.

Comment: I have a file on disk call fileA.log
I copy it by doing cat fileA.log > fileB.log
Then I run the code twice, each with different file. FileA.log takes maybe 20secs to read but fileB.log onlys takes 2secs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they stored in different places (eg. one on a network share?)

How are you timing? Are you sure you're not forgetting to reset a timer, so the timing you get from the second one includes the first one?

Are you clearing any variables between the two tests to make sure the timing is fair?

Comment: No I rebuild and start the app again. Files are stored on c:Drive and timing is done before and after the line calling DateTime.Now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have enough memory to load the second file after you load the first file? So PC emulates RAM using HDD?

Comment: Hi Bogdan, no I don't load both files at same time. I build and run my code and files A loads in say 30secs. Then I shut down completely and rebuild and start code with fileB, but that takes 2 secs.  All I have done is changed filename in code...